# Not Saving Source Code in CKEditor [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When I add code directly to the source code and save it without previewing it, CKEditor does not save this change.

I am using CKEditor 4 for Angular. Would you help me with this topic?

Comment: Could you please add more information, what do you mean by "add code to the source code and save it without previewing it"

Comment: **@TheViralGriffin** First of all, I apologize for my bad english. I press the 'Source' button and write my html code. If I click the 'save' button without clicking the 'source' button again later, it does not save what I have written. https://i.ibb.co/sV8LDDM/image.png